Azure Configuration Store valueUpdated event data does not contain new value, how do I get it?
I have a webhook configured to respond to valueUpdated events from an Azure App Configuration Store event subscription. My webhook is intended to respond to valueUpdated events when the value of the key storing an NLog configuration XML string gets changed. My webhook gets called when I change the value in the config store but the event payload does not contain the new value. How do I obtain the new value so my webhook logic can update the configuration of the currently running NLog service?
I have tried attempting to force a configuration reload by using the EventGridEvent object to create a push notification that I pass to the ConfigurationRefresher.ProcessPushNotification method with a timespan of zero for the second parameter in order to immediately invalidate the local cache. Then I call RefreshAsync to load a fresh set of values into the local configuration service from the config store. It executes but the new values are not loaded. My webhook calls the following method when it receives an event.
private async Task HandleConfigStoreNLogUpdate(EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, AppConfigurationKeyValueModifiedEventData appConfigurationKeyValueModifiedEventData)
{
  eventGridEvent.TryCreatePushNotification(out PushNotification pushNotification);
  WebApiApplication.ConfigurationRefresher.ProcessPushNotification(pushNotification, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0));
  await WebApiApplication.ConfigurationRefresher.RefreshAsync();
  WebApiApplication.ApplyNewLoggerConfiguration();
}

The Apply new LoggerConfiguration method uses a global variable LastNLogConfigurationXml to detect changes in the value associated with key "Insights:Nlog:API"
public static void ApplyNewLoggerConfiguration()
{
  string nlogConfigString = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Insights:NLog:API");
  if (!nlogConfigString.Equals(LastNLogConfigurationXml, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  {
    XmlLoggingConfiguration xmlLogConfig = XmlLoggingConfiguration.CreateFromXmlString(nlogConfigString);

    LogManager.Configuration = xmlLogConfig;
    LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
    LastNLogConfigurationXml = nlogConfigString;
  }
}

I was expecting the updated value to be in the data supplied to the webhook. What is the point of calling the webhook if there is no useful information with it? Is there a way to obtain the new value using any of the information in the event? My attempts to force the AzureAppConfiguration service to immediately invalidate its cache and give me new values have not worked.

It is by design in Azure App Configuration that the Event Grid event does not contain the configuration value for data security. The event serves only as a notification, informing your application that something has changed. Your application can then fetch the latest value from your App Configuration store with proper authentication.
Here is the sequence to get the updated configuration:

Call ConfigurationRefresher.ProcessPushNotification to reset the refresh wait time to zero.
Call RefreshAsync to trigger a refresh. Since the wait time is zero, it will check if your registered watching key, also known as the sentinel key, has changed.
If the sentinel key has changed, the configuration will be reloaded from your App Configuration store; otherwise, no action will be taken.

I noticed that you have already implemented steps 1 and 2 in the code you shared. Please ensure that your sentinel key has changed. You can also enable debug logging to better understand what is happening.
